# Making JAXB generate an XML processing instruction

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb

I am generating XML dynamically using JAXB.

Now, I want to convert it to HTML using XSL. How can i include

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="">
```

in the dynamically generated XML?

Comment: Do you mean you want to include a stylesheet reference in the JAXB output?

Answer (score 11):

All the solutions here are pretty ugly and verbose. Simply set the line inside the `Mashaller` object specifying the additional header.

```
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = ...
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", 
    "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='nameoffile.xsl' ?>");
```

This example will output an XML object to a file using a stylesheet and format the elements nicely for humans to read. The object `myXmlObject` is of class `MyXmlClass`, and will be written to `file`, formatted by a stylesheet given by `xslUrl`:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyXmlClass.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
//Need to use a Writer to marshal with the XSL
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
//Do this or else the XML is all one line and not human friendly...
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders",
        "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href=\"" +
        xslUrl +
        "\" ?>");
marshaller.marshal(myXmlObject, fw);
```

---

**Update**

In recent version of JAXB we need to use property key as `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders` like below.

```
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = ...
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", 
    "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='nameoffile.xsl' ?>");
```

Comment: This is the elegant way to do it, but it won't work if you are doing `marshal()` to a `File` (for example). It requires the output to be a Writer or Stream. Once you are aware of this it should be simple matter to wrap your `File` in a `FileWriter`.

Comment: @KevinSadler Your edit has been rejected by the community. I added the edit, but it has been uglyfied. Please, prettify it such that the edit will be linked to you! Thanks!

Comment: OK I have reformatted it and altered the comment slightly, I hope it will be accepted as I think it adds a couple of useful things.

Comment: Just a slight note: the supported properties depend on the used implemenation of JAXB

Comment: For the record: using the default Jaxb implementation in Java 8, which uses the marshaller javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl under the hood, this very elegant method unfortunately does not work anymore.

Comment: only working using `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders`

Answer (score 4):

You could use a StringWriter to first write the stylesheet information into it, and then marshal the object into it:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
//add processing instructions "by hand" with escaped quotation marks
//or single marks
writer.println("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
writer.println("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"\">");

//create and configure marshaller to leave out processing instructions
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

//marshal to the StringWriter
marshaller.marshal(someObject,writer);
//get the string representation 
String str = writer.toString();
```

Of course you can also directly print to every other output stream you want, e.g. files or Sytstem.out.

Answer (score 2):

See how it's done in [rexsl-core](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-core), part of ReXSL XSL/JAXB/JAX-RS framework: [XslResolver](http://trac.fazend.com/rexsl/browser/rexsl/tags/rexsl-0.4/rexsl/rexsl-core/src/main/java/com/rexsl/core/XslResolver.java):

```
final String header = String.format(
  "\n<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='%s'?>",
  StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("my-stylesheet.xsl")
);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", header);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext;
try {
       jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SomeObject.class});

       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       writer.write("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
       writer.write("\n");
       writer.write("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"\">");
       writer.write("\n");

       Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
       jaxbMarshaller.marshal(someobject, writer);
}
```

Comment: Please try to answer in words and not only in code. And since you answer so late, how does your answer differ from the other ones?