# How to add DOCTYPE and xml processing instructions when marshalling with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am marshalling (serializing) JAXB beans to output stream. How can I add DOCTYPE declaration and xml processing instructions to ouput?

I am doing currently marshalling like this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.package");
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);
marshaller.setSchema(schema);

marshaller.marshal(object, output);
```

I'd like have output that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Something SYSTEM "some.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="some.xsl"?>
```

JAXB bean are generated code so I don't want to change them.

There are some hacks and undocumented tricks (see [Making JAXB generate an XML processing instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153219/making-jaxb-generate-an-xml-processing-instruction))  to add the [xml processing instructions](http://java.itags.org/java-enterprise/36260/) and [doctype](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=235226). But what is the preferred or right way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The JAXB RI has a proprietary `Marshaller` property `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders` (see [XML Preamble Control](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1.13/docs/vendorProperties.html#xmldec):

> This property allows you to specify an
>   XML preamble (`<?xml ...>`
>   declaration) and any additional PIs,
>   comments, `DOCTYPE` declaration that
>   follows it. This property takes effect
>   only when you are marshalling to
>   `OutputStream`, `Writer`, or
>   `StreamResult`. Note that this
>   property interacts with the
>   `Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT` property.
>   If that property is untouched or set
>   to false, then JAXB would always write
>   its XML preamble, so this property can
>   be only used to write PIs, comments,
>   `DOCTYPE`, etc. On the other hand, if
>   it is set to true, then JAXB will not
>   write its own XML preamble, so this
>   property may contain custom XML
>   preamble.

This should do what you need. If you're using Java5 and the JAXB RI, then this should just work.  If you're using Java6 with its included JAXB implementation, the `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders` name might be different, so try `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders` instead.

Comment: you meant the other way right? if you are using JAXB RI then com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders will work, if jaxb impl is used then its is com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders right?