# how to add DOCTYPE in jaxb marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i am using spring boot with jdk1.8. I can Marshall Java Object to XML using jaxb xml but i want to add DOCTYPE on XML output.

current xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

What i want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Example SYSTEM "example.dtd">
```

Below is my JAXB

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.PropertyException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;


 public class JAXBExample {

 public String  CreateXML() {

 PDXIReq pdxiReq = new PDXIReq(new Header("KO0haj000", "SS_ASED", 
     "CTY_IPC"), new Request("ACT_ACTION", 20131106, 111816, 
     9181626L, 0,1024, "1AJHSYQW36276354"));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

 try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PDXIReq.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", 
      "\n<!DOCTYPE Example SYSTEM  \"example.dtd\">");
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(pdxiReq, sw);


       } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return sw.toString();

   }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919294/how-to-add-doctype-and-xml-processing-instructions-when-marshalling-with-jaxb
Try using `OutputStream`, `Writer`, or `StreamResult` instead of `StringWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My post above is already correct when i run again.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PDXIReq.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    // output pretty printed
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", 
  "\n<!DOCTYPE Example SYSTEM  \"example.dtd\">");
```