# Java JAXB - link output to XSLT document

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am producing a XML file by the help of JAXB.

```
public String getPrices() {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext context;
    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AllMerchandises.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(this.allMerchandises, writer);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```

the resulting XML String looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:merchandises xmlns:ns2="example/test/workspace">
<merchandise id="1">
    <name>Cat</name>
    <price>50</price>
</merchandise>
<merchandise id="2">
    <name>Dog</name>
    <price>100</price>
</merchandise>
<merchandise id="3">
    <name>Ape</name>
    <price>150</price>
</merchandise>
<merchandise id="4">
    <name>Gorilla</name>
    <price>200</price>
</merchandise>
<merchandise id="5">
    <name>Elephant</name>
    <price>250</price>
</merchandise>
</ns2:merchandises>
```

It is my task that the document could be showed a little bit designed in a browser by using XSLT. Therefor I need to include the .xsl in my XML file. Is there a maybe a way to tell the JAXB marshaller to make a inclusion? What could I do otherwise? 
I need to include sth like this as 2nd line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myfile.xsl"?>
```

thanks for every good idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making JAXB generate an XML processing instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153219/making-jaxb-generate-an-xml-processing-instruction)

Comment: thanks very much - I searched before I asked but did not get to that one.. it is exactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up using the same solution as described in this thread.

[Making JAXB generate an XML processing instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153219/making-jaxb-generate-an-xml-processing-instruction)